# How do I create 3d plot of a sigmoid or linear function in 3d?

Tags: plotting, scripting

How can i plot a 2d function (y=x) in 3d with decaying z values. Something like this

[image]

One side of the curve can be flat at max too,like the right side, I am mostly interested in decaying values depending on the arbitrary 2d function.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Plot3D[z = Exp[x y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -4, 4}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
But in this case i dont know what to put inside Exp function as it should represent somehow the 2d function.

Comment: Here is something i have tried. You can see parabola decaying. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&ei=F7wlW6DdH4HRswG9yI_ACA&q=Exp%28x%5E2%2Fy%29&oq=Exp%28x%5E2%2Fy%29&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30k1l2j0i5i30k1l2j0i8i30k1l6.22401.22554.0.23110.2.2.0.0.0.0.86.166.2.2.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.2.166....0.ojlTVSkU3Fo

Answer (score 3):

It's basically not hard. Let us look at the function $y(x) = -x$

```
Plot[-x, {x, -3, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-3, 2}, {-3, 2}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see, this is basically the line of the rim when you look at your 3D plot from above. If you want *decay*, then you need a notion for the *distance from this line*. This however is really easy, because you just use your original function $y(x) = -x$ and bring everything on one side

$$0 = y + x\\f(x,y) = y + x$$

All points {x,y} that fulfill $f(x,y)=0$ lie on the line. If you square the right side, then you get something that is always positive or zero. It is zero for points on the line and will be larger, the more your point is away from the line.

$$d(x,y) = (x+y)^2$$

Since we want to turn this around (points on the line get a large z-value and points further away get a smaller z-value), we can use `Exp` to help us.

```
Plot3D[Exp[-(y + x)^2], {x, -3, 2}, {y, -3, 2}, BoxRatios -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By the way, it is of course possible to make it more flat and steeper

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But to know exactly what you want is impossible without details about the thing you call *decay*.

Comment: Thank you for the help halirutan. About the sigmoid: I came up with seomthing like this Plot3D[Exp[-(y + 1/(1 + Exp[-x ]))^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, AxesLabel -> Automatic] , although it looks like sigmoid and decaying in z, there are some zigzaggy lines and i dont know how to make it parameterised so i can change the shape of the sigmoid. It would be amazing for me if you could help me with that.